# How to suppress Cell Reference when loading sheet to workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I suppress the following message when I import a worksheet from another workbook to a new workbook.

[image]

How can I skip these altogether? I dont want to change any references.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Import()

Dim masterWB As Workbook
Dim dailyWB As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Set Current Workbook as Master
Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("file name")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Copy the Range from DailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
dailyWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:F200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("TEST").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
Columns("A:F").Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

'Close the Workbook without saving
dailyWB.Close False
'Clear the Variables
Set dailyWB = Nothing
Set masterWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to move `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after you copied to another workbook.

```
Sub Import()

    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim dailyWB As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
    'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
    Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("file name")


    'Copy the Range from DailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
    dailyWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:F200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("TEST").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    Columns("A:F").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Close the Workbook without saving
    dailyWB.Close False
    'Clear the Variables
    Set dailyWB = Nothing
    Set masterWB = Nothing

    End Sub
```